# Java lambda: catch exception on a duplicate key mapping

Tags: java, lambda, exception, java-8

I have a `Map<Person, Long> personToSalary` which I would like to map to another `Map<String, Long> lastnameToSalary`.

Now, this can potentially lead that two `Person` objects that are normally not equal, will have the equal `lastname` property and this will cause the duplicate key insertion to a new map. This is OK, as long as I can catch this exception, and throw my own. But not sure how to do so.

Here is the code.

```
   Map<Person, Long> personToSalaray = getMappings();

   // lastname to salary
   Map<String, Long> personToSalary.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(toMap(
                    e -> e.getKey().getLastname(),
                    e -> e.getValue()));
```

While this works, it will potentially throw an exception on duplicate key insertion (same lastname). How to catch it? I can't declare a try-catch inside of toMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Javadocs of [`Collectors.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-):

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to `Object.equals(Object)`), an `IllegalStateException` is thrown when the collection operation is performed. If the mapped keys may have duplicates, use `toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)` instead.

So the solution should not be catching an exception but using the other `toMap` overload specifically designed to treat duplicates. The documentation of that method gives an example close to your scenario:

> There are multiple ways to deal with collisions between multiple elements mapping to the same key. The other forms of toMap simply use a merge function that throws unconditionally, but you can easily write more flexible merge policies. For example, if you have a stream of Person, and you want to produce a "phone book" mapping name to address, but it is possible that two persons have the same name, you can do as follows to gracefully deals with these collisions, and produce a Map mapping names to a concatenated list of addresses:
>
> ```
> Map<String, String> phoneBook
>      people.stream().collect(toMap(Person::getName,
>                                    Person::getAddress,
>                                    (s, a) -> s + ", " + a));
> ```

Answer (score 2):

use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

```
Map<String, Long> personToSalary.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(toMap(
                    e -> e.getKey().getLastname(),
                    e -> e.getValue(),
                    (a, b) -> a // just choose one of the duplicates, or you can put more logic to decide which one you need
));
```

Comment: So BinaryOperator will operate on the keys from a new map being created, ie in my case the String lastnames?

Comment: @wesleyy It will operate on the values not the keys, i.e. the Long values.

Comment: @AR.3 But only if the keys are the same, right? So (a,b) are Long values, but I could throw an exception here saying "Same lastname occurred twice"?

Comment: @wesleyy Yes a and b are long values for the same keys. I'm not sure if you can throw an exception in the lambda but if catching and throwing exceptions is needed, why not simply use the first `toMap`. As already mentioned, it does throw an IllegalStateException in case of duplicate keys.